# Rails session in Heroku is always empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku

I have developed a little app that uses session.
In the **local server** it's working perfectly - I can store and retrieve some data to/from the session.
But when I pushed the code to **Heroku** platform, my app does not work. The session is always empty.
I don't understand where the problem? Any ideas.

Comment: The default rails/heroku session (stored in the cookies). I didn't change anything in rails config.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the session is ok. I have added the debug output everywhere and I see that the session is ok. The problem comes from the internal app's logic.